# lwip tcp pcb->snd_queuelen is showing greater value than TCP_SND_QUEUELEN

Tags: tcp, lwip

I was trying to implement tcp lwip for my work(sender).I have configured the TCP send buffer space TCP_SND_QUEUELEN as 32. But when there is a packet loss pcb->snd_queuelen is showing greater value than 32 and client is getting disconnected.Why and how to solve this? I have configured TCP_MSS as 1160 and TCP_SND_BUF   is (TCP_MSS * 16).  Anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a greater value than TCP_SND_QUEUELEN is normal only. Already there is further logic to get rid from this situation. since the flag MSG_DONTWAIT is passed while sending the packet,sending operation can not be blocked,if so it will return error. This is the reason for closing the socket.